# Creating a custom search with navigation down using EditText and Spinner

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm trying to create a custom search using EditText with navigation down using Spinner. i want to make it like the image below.

**Base Design Image - >**
[image]

but here what i have now

**Done Design - >**

[image]

**here is my xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchFilter"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_blue"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:background="@drawable/filter_bg"
            />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/searchFilter"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**My filter_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:thickness="0dp">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#b71c1c" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

anyone can help me to make it like the first image? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change your layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchFilter"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_blue"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:background="@drawable/filter_bg"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

using relative layout and not setting component relation properly was the issue.  it is easy to use liner layout here.